# How do I compare two rows in excel and highlight all new or deleted entries?

Tags: excel, vba

I have two spreadsheets. A master spreadsheet with 3 rows (project IDs and 'where are we', severity level), and receive a new spreadsheet every day with (projects IDs and 'where are we', severity level). Currently, I manually check all entries one by one to see if one project ID/severity got deleted or added/changed, and check this first by looking at project ID.

I'm looking for a formula/vba code to quickly see if a new project got added or deleted - and if a severity level got changed.

The easiest way for me to check currently is to copy the row of Project IDs from the other sheet and just do a {=AND(A1:A5000=B1:B5000)} to see if they match. If they match completely, it will provide a TRUE, if not, i'll look for a way to find the missing or added entry which is just taking too much time.

I do the same for the severity level.

how can I quickly check if a new entry has been added/deleted? This is an exercise which takes me a lot of time and should be able to automate much better.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that you don't have thousands of entries I'd go for something like this.

```
Dim cell as Range

lastrow_everydaysheet = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

list_projectids = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A" & lastrow_everydaysheet).Address

For Each cell In Sheets("Day 1").Range(list_projectids)

project_id = cell.value

lastrow_mastersheet = Sheets("Master").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Sheets("Master").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A" & lastrow_mastersheet).Select


 Set project_id_found = Selection.Find(What:=project_id, after:=ActiveCell, 
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If Not project_id_found Is Nothing Then

' don't do nothing or paint the interior green

Else

Sheets("Day 1").Activate
cell.sSelect
ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 20

End if

Next cell
```

This is to see if some project id was added. To delete, exchange the sheet Master for Day 1, Day 2...
You could use for severity to.
The code go for every cell on a specific range and do a vlookup on another range, if the value is found then makes something, if not, it does anything else.

Hope I could help.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to amend that to get this to work. 1000x times thanks.